# Cómo sumar inputs dinámicos con JavaScript y MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Quisiera saber cómo hacer para poder sumar inputs dinámicos.

He leido un poco pero sólo he visto que es con JavaScript y jQuery. No he encontrado la manera de hacerlo. Tengo una base de datos de donde saco alumnos y a esos alumnos quisiera sumarles las notas. Más que todo es para un cuadro de notas.

Esto es lo que llevo de los inputs. Sí me los tira, pero no sé cómo sumarlos e insertarlos.

```
<?php
$url=$con[8];
                    toalu();

                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)){

                         ?>
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $row[2]?>" /></br /><br />

                     <?php }
                     ?>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
```

Comment: lo agregué a tu pregunta. Su hay algo para sumarle, encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: @JavierReyes Que es lo que recibes en tu consulta? Que tipo de valor es `$row[2]`. Y menciones Quieres sumarlos e insertarlos? a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: @JavierReyes agregar información en lo comentarios **no es lo mismo que** editar tu pregunta y agregar la información allí. Cuidado con eso

Answer (score 1):

Para sumar inputs de forma dinámica tan solo basta añadirles un listener para el evento `input`. Éste tipo de evento se dispara en cualquier cambio que ocurra sobre la caja de texto.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

[].forEach.call(inputs, function (input, i) {
    input.addEventListener('input', function () {
        var sumPrev = 0;
        [].forEach.call(inputs, function (input, x) {
            if (i !== x) {
                sumPrev += parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
          }
      });
      var _total = (parseFloat(input.value) + sumPrev).toFixed(2);
      var _avg = (_total / inputs.length).toFixed(2);
  });
```

Para registrar éstos datos en tu base de datos necesitas enviarlos de algún modo. Puedes hacerlo de la manera normal o mediante ajax. Ésto depende mucho de si estás usando algún tipo de framework o PHP simple.

Por ejemplo, caso que estés usando PHP simple, te basta recuperar los datos mediante `$_POST`.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = {
    total: _total,
    avg: _avg,
    scores: []
  };

  // obtiene las notas
  [].forEach.call(inputs, i => {
    data.scores.push(parseFloat(i.value));
  });

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '/archivo.php');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status === 200) { // exito
      if (request.readyState === 4) { // petición completada
        var respuesta = request.responseText;
        // mostrar mensaje de éxito o algo
      }
    } else {
      var error = request.responseText;
      // hacer algo con el mensaje error
    }
  }
  request.send(JSON.stringify(data)); // se envía el json
});
```

Y en `archivo.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
  $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

  // registrar los datos

  echo 'Notas registradas';
}
```

Te dejo [una demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/sv82qff3/) de la parte JavaScript.